# Unable to install php_ibm_db2.dll on PHP 5.6

Tags: windows, php, ibm, db2

I'm getting the following error when trying to start Apache. I've confirmed the extension is in the folder and other extensions such as `sqlsrv` work just fine. This is the only one that seems to fail on load. I'm running 32-bit PHP and Apache.

[extension download](https://pecl.php.net/package/ibm_db2/1.9.9/windows)

```
[17-Oct-2017 16:45:44 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.6.25/ext/php_ibm_db2_nts.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

 in Unknown on line 0

[17-Oct-2017 16:45:44 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.6.25/ext/php_ibm_db2_ts.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

 in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: OS linux or windows ?

Comment: It is windows 7